# Background image not setting to white | adding styling to text

Tags: flutter

Kind of two questions in one here... still new to flutter and learning as I go.

1. My background color will not change to white. All resources on flutter.dev did not seem viable. Currently, I am using the most suggested answer which is that of `backgroundColor: Colors.white`. Any thoughts as to why this is not working?

`class App extends StatelessWidget {`

````
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Onboarding1',
      theme: ThemeData(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        fontFamily: 'fonts/Avenir-Bold',
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
    );
  }
}```
````

2. I want to be able to style the text in the column, but TextStle is throwing an error. What is the best way to adjust the text style when in a column? Would it just be best to use a scaffold?

@override

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Image.asset(
          "assets/Onboarding1_Photo.png",
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.7,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
        Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('Some Text'),
            style: TextStyle(
            )
          ],
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Update based on the answer... What am I still doing wrong?

```
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Onboarding1',
      theme: ThemeData(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
        fontFamily: 'fonts/Avenir-Bold',
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Onboarding1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Image.asset(
            "assets/Onboarding1_Photo.png",
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.7,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('Some Text', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24)),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated Answer with example:

```
class Onboarding1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Image.asset(
            "assets/Onboarding1_Photo.png",
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.7,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('Some Text', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24)),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Original Answer :
The field you're looking for in your ThemeData is `scaffoldBackgroundColor`.

```
ThemeData(
   scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
   fontFamily: 'fonts/Avenir-Bold',
   visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity),
```

Then wrap your column in a scaffold and it'll work.

As for your text style, in your code the `style` is outside of the text widget and it needs to be inside and you need to define a `TextStyle` with the properties.

```
Text('Some Text',
 style: TextStyle(
  color: Colors.blue, 
  fontSize: 20),
),
```

Admittedly styling text in Flutter is a bit verbose for my taste. For that reason I have my own reusabe custom text widget that saves time on my most used properties of text.

```
class MyTextWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final double fontSize;
  final Color color;
  final double spacing;

  const MyTextWidget(
      {Key key, this.text, this.fontSize, this.color, this.spacing})
      : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(
      text != null ? text : ' ',

// this is part of the google fonts package it won't work if you don't have it in your project but you get the idea

      style: kGoogleFontOpenSansCondensed.copyWith(
          fontSize: fontSize ?? 20,
          color: color ?? Colors.white70,
          letterSpacing: spacing ?? 1.0),
    );
  }
}
```

Then when I need a text widget it looks like this

```
MyTextWidget(
   text: 'Some text', 
   fontSize: 25, 
   color: Colors.white54)
```

Comment: can you please check the edit to my original post? What am I still doing wrong?

Comment: You put your Scaffold inside the Column and the column needs to be inside the scaffold. Generally speaking, a `Scaffold` will be the root widget of any basic page.

Comment: Also not sure what you're trying to accomplish with that Container with the transparent background. But based on your other post that I answered, I suggest starting with just Scaffold->Column->Image like I had in the other thread and go from there. Having that Container set to infinity height and width is also probably causing problems.

Comment: Just trying to accomplish the design in the other question you had answered. I will try the Scaffold, column, image method. Thanks!

Comment: Also be aware of the order you list your children in Columns. Based on your other post you want the image on top of the screen, and here you have the text widget above the image. If you still want the image on top, it needs to be the first child in the Column.

Comment: Yikes, okay. Will do

Comment: Sorry, disregard that last comment it was something weird that happened when I was adjusting the code in my IDE. See updated answer with example.

Comment: Okay, amazing. Thanks so much. Last question for you, the background colour still won't change despite the columns being in the Scaffold. Any thoughts? I edited the post to contain most recent code.

Comment: did you change the property in the themeData to `scaffoldBackgroundColor`?

Comment: Yes, as  shown it is         `scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white,`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228767/discussion-between-loren-a-and-kyleusa).